# ExtJS 3: How to define different actions to different rows based on the values in the row?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs3

In a `grid panel` which supports adding,editing and deleting rows, I want to define different actions to different rows based on the values in the row. Like,

On `add`, one new row will be added in the grid. I have a `column` in my grid which has a `combo editor`( I can select either `yes` or `no`). If the value is `no`, I will disable the next column which is a textfield and also another column which has a button with a hyperlink.
And if the value is `yes`, I want the textfield and the button to be enabled.

I tried to get the textfield and the button 
by using `Ext.getCmp()` and use `disable()`, but what happens then is, the `action` will be applied to the column in all the rows of the grid, whereas I want it to be applied to only that particular row where I have selected the  value.

To be more clear, let me explain it with an example.. Assuming that my grid used for storing phone number entries has  3 columns,

1. column 1 - `Has phone number?`
2. column 2 - `Provide phone number`
3. column 3 - `Look up the user name`

Here, I will add row 1 to the grid,choose value `no` for the `has phone number` flag, so based on my code, I will use `Ext.getCmp` and get the textfield and button and invoke `disable` method, so that column 2 and 3 is disabled.

In row 2, I will choose value `yes` for the flag,so ideally I should be able to modify the column 2 and 3 of row 2.

But, what happens is, along with row 2, the columns in row 1 also is getting enabled because I chose `yes` this time.

So, I wanted to know how to apply some actions to the columns of the row based on the value for that particular row. And the next row, should be independent of the actions applied to the current row...  Looking for some help/ guidance in this resolving this issue.

I am using Ext JS version 3.4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current record in the `getClass` and `handler` method to change the aspect and action of the column depending on the row :

```
new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
store: myStore,
columns: [
    {
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        width: 50,
        items: [
            {
                getClass: function(v, meta, rec) {  // Or return a class from a function
                    if (rec.get('change') < 0) {
                        this.items[1].tooltip = 'Do not buy!';
                        return 'alert-col';
                    } else {
                        this.items[1].tooltip = 'Buy stock';
                        return 'buy-col';
                    }
                },
                handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    var rec = store.getAt(rowIndex);
                    alert("Buy " + rec.get('company'));
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    //any other columns here
]
});
```

Comment: Can I use the above methods even if it is not actioncolumn??

Comment: no, but you can use the renderer config : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Column-cfg-renderer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put a condition on the event beforeedit or maybe cellclick.

So if the condition is not respected, you return false and the user will not be able to edit.

example:

```
    listeners: {
       beforeedit: function(e) {

          //get the value of the column before
           var befCol = e.row[indexofBefCol]; 

           //check your condition
           if(befCol.getValue() === "no") {
                return false; //return false to stop edition
           }
                  }
   }
```

I haven't test my code maybe you will have to modify it but I think you will be able to do something with that.

Hope this help.

Good luck!

Comment: I have tried something similar to this, but the action is being applied to all columns, not for a particular row!

Comment: add an if condition or a switch case to perform the action on specific column